# Spring 3.0 - @Transactional runtime change timeout

Tags: hibernate, spring, weblogic, websphere

We are using Spring 3.0/Hibernate/Weblogic-websphere - Oracle in my project.
For transaction management, we are using @Transactional annotation. I have two Questions/concerns, which I hope to get some help from you guys.

1) Is it possible to change the Transaction's timeout during the runtime based on a condition?

2) Is it possible to set the timeout per method in a config xml but still use @transactional annotation?

Please help me out!!

- Mohan

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure about first question, but the answer for the second question is Yes.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html

According to this documentation `@Transactional` annotoation has timeout paramter:

Comment: hi Danny, I am using the timeout parameter on the @Transactional Annotation. But my problem is , once if my code goes to production, I will not have access to code to adjust to its optimal value depending on production working conditions. So, I am looking it to be set from a configuration xml file, so that all we have to do is to change it and restart webserver.